# ASP.NET download csv file as zip?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, dotnetzip

I've been reading through:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-data-from-SQL-Server-to-CSV-file-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Rather than only have the option to download as csv as described there in:

```
                //Download the CSV file.
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                Response.Output.Write(csv);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
```

is there a way using native asp.net to first zip the csv output from the csv variable in Response.Output.Write(csv); so that the user downloads SqlExport.zip rather than SqlExport.csv?

Comment: No. If you want to zip the data then you need to zip the data. It's not difficult but you need to do it yourself.

Comment: https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/create-zip-files-on-http-request-without-intermediate-files-using-aspdotnet-mvc-razor-pages-and-endpoints

Comment: @JeremyLakeman are you going to copy the core code and add an answer with reference to this article? Link could die, bounty on offer...

Comment: Yeah, I was working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly based on [this](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/create-zip-files-on-http-request-without-intermediate-files-using-aspdotnet-mvc-razor-pages-and-endpoints), you can create a zip file while streaming it to the client;

```cs
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"SqlExport.zip\"");

using var archive = new ZipArchive(Response.Body, ZipArchiveMode.Create);

var entry = archive.CreateEntry("SqlExport.csv");
using var entryStream = entry.Open();

entryStream.Write(csv); // write the actual content here

entryStream.Flush();
```

Though rather than appending to a single `csv` string, you should probably consider using a `StreamWriter` to write each snippet of text directly into the response stream. Substituting from your linked csv example;

```cs
using var sw = new StreamWriter(entryStream);

// TODO write header

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        //Add the Data rows.
        await sw.WriteAsync(row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
    }
    //Add new line.
    await sw.WriteLineAsync();
}
```

Though that is a terrible example of a csv file. Rather than substituting `';'` characters, the string should be quoted & all quotes escaped.

However `Response.Body` is only available in .net 5 / core. To write directly to a http response in .net 4.8 or earlier, you'll have to write your own `HttpContent`. Putting everything together, including a better csv formatter;

```cs
public class ZipContent : HttpContent
{
    private DataTable dt;
    private string name;

    public ZipContent(DataTable dt, string name = null)
    {
        this.dt = dt;
        this.name = name ?? dt.TableName;
        Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
        Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = $"{name}.zip"
        };
    }

    private string formatCsvValue(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";
        if (value.Contains('"') || value.Contains(',') || value.Contains('\r') || value.Contains('\n'))
            return $"\"{value.Replace("\"", "\"\"")}\"";
        return value;
    }

    private IEnumerable<DataColumn> Columns()
    {
        // Why is this not already an IEnumerable<DataColumn>?
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            yield return col;
    }

    protected override async Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        using var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create);

        var entry = archive.CreateEntry($"{name}.csv");
        using var entryStream = entry.Open();
        using var sw = new StreamWriter(entryStream);

        await sw.WriteLineAsync(
            string.Join(",",
                Columns()
                .Select(c => formatCsvValue(c.ColumnName))
            ));

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(
                string.Join(",", 
                    row.ItemArray
                    .Select(o => formatCsvValue(o?.ToString()))
                ));
        }
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Can I ask if you tested that C# code to see if it works? If so, I can take your word for it and award the bounty. Then I can create another question relating to converting it to vb.net for ASP.NET 4.7. I've been trying for an hour to get it going with vb.net but have been stuck on Response.Body giving a vb.net compilation error. I also had to add References to System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.

Comment: Ah, right, asp-net. I'm so used to the .net 5 / core api. `HttpResponseMessage` / `StreamContent` require a pre-prepared stream that you can read from. If you want to avoid using a `MemoryStream` as a buffer, you might need to write your own `HttpContent` overriding `.CopyTo` and write the zip into the response from there.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I've created another follow up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182302/asp-net-zip-and-download-string-variable so I could accept your answer here.

Comment: @user1946932 the new question essentially asks people to rewrite this in VB.NET, that's why it was closed. This answer already solves the problem. If the data is stored in a string already, all you have to do is write that string into the ZipArchiveEntry's stream

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ZipArchive Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0)

you can use `public System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry CreateEntry (string entryName);` to create an ZipEntry nd add it to an archive

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer because it still leaves a lot for the OP to do.

Comment: cant commend on stackoverflow yet

Comment: That doesn't mean that you should post answers that aren't answers instead.